# Alfresco Create User From Filter

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

By taking reference from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517122/alfresco-sso-with-cookie/9638441#) and I am successful in authenticating the user. But this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517122/alfresco-sso-with-cookie/9638441#) does not authenticate new users that are not present in alfresco. I have also explored SSOAuthenticationFilter.java to find how alfresco creates user when external authentication subsystem is used but not able figure out how the creation of user takes place in the mentioned subsystem. It would be great if anyone could provide the way to create and authenticate user that are not present in alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Alfresco do you use ?

Recent version provide a similar function, please take a look to : http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/auth-basics.html
The only thing you need to need is define the header name in your global properties files.

About the new user creation, in Alfresco behaviour it's based on the synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn properties : http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/sync-props.html

When an unknown user try to loggin Alfresco will trigger a synchronization.

Y.